# mongoDB query using $match and $group (filter last 24 hours logged data and group with id and count)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, mongodb-query

what I am trying to do is, filter only last 24 hour logs and
group by userId and count how many time it logged

here is my mongoDB collection's schema

| Key | Type |
| --- | --- |
| timestamp(ISODate) | Date |
| ... | ... |
| transactionLogs_docs | Array |
| - [0] | Object |
| - userId | String |
| - ... | ... |

following is my MongoDB Query statement

```
db.getCollection('integrated_transaction_logs').aggregate(
[                 
                {'$group' : 
                {
                    '_id' : '$transactionLogs_docs.userId', 
                    'count' : {'$sum' : 1} 
                }},
                {'$match' : {'timestamp' : {'$gte' : new Date(new Date().getTime() - 86400000 * 30), '$lte' : new Date()} } }
])
```

with only $match or $group it works but when I put them together,
it doesn't work....:S

Comment: every stage should be in separate {} object bracket, you have added both stages in same object, see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VQwRXCIY2oC)

Comment: I posted wrongly when I write on stackoverflow :S sorry
just modified it. but still it's not working...any tip for me? :S @turivishal

Comment: remember: put the $match stage before the $group for better performance and also to have what to filter

Comment: You need to understand first usage of stages and how pipeline stages works, see [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) and you can't use `timestamp` in `$match` stage because you have not defined that field in $group stage, as per your query you can access only 2 fields `_id` and `count` in `$match` stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $match before $group stage